# What is the email matching regex in basic regex for grep?

Tags: shell, command-line, grep, regular-expression

I created a text file and put some email addresses in it. Then I used grep to find them. Indeed it worked:

```
# pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-z]{2,}"
# grep -E $pattern regexfile
```

but only as long I kept the -E option for an extended regular expression. How do I need to change the above regex in order to use grep without -E option?

Comment: BTW, in case glenn’s O’Reilly reference elicits a **TL;DR** response, this regex is _way_ short of what you need to match real-world email addresses; see [Email Address Syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax) at Wikipedia, for starters.

Comment: Your regex isn't even close to correct for email address.  For example, it doesn't recognize `fred-smith@company.com`.  Many other examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be aware that matching email addresses is a LOT harder that what you have. See
[an excerpt from the Mastering Regular Expressions book](http://examples.oreilly.com/9781565922570/readme.html)

However, to answer your question, for a basic regular expression, your quantifiers need to be one of `*`,  `\+` or `\{m,n\}` (with the backslashes)

```
pattern='^[a-zA-Z0-9]\+@[a-zA-Z0-9]\+\.[a-z]\{2,\}'
grep "$pattern" regexfile
```

You need to quote the pattern variable

Comment: why is it important to quote the variable ?

Comment: The answer to that is spelled out in great detail here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667

Comment: What are the possible symbols in an email address, before `@`?  At least you need to contain `.`, `-` and `_`, to start with?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2953197/7552