# grep: problem with regular expression

Tags: grep

Can anyone explain why this does not work?

```
grep -ne '[A-Za-z]{1,30}\ [A-Z][a-z]{1,30}\W[A-Za-z]{1,30}\ [0-9]{1,30}\W[0-9]{5}\ [A-Za-z]{1,30}(\ [A-Za-z]{1,30})?' emails
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Matching addresses

Comment: Include the input, current output  and expected output.

Comment: (possibly) Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194912/what-is-the-email-matching-regex-in-basic-regex-for-grep

Comment: For one, because the `{n,m}` needs extended regular expressions (`grep -E`) or backslashes. See: [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y) and grep's man page too

Answer (score 3):

First, you are using extended regular expression (ERE) syntax like `{}`, `()` and `?`. Add option `-E` to use ERE or do escape `{}` and `()` with backslashes and replace `?` like this: `grep -ne '[A-Za-z]\{1,30\} [A-Z][a-z]\{1,30\}\W[A-Za-z]\{1,30\} [0-9]\{1,30\}\W[0-9]\{5\} [A-Za-z]\{1,30\}\( [A-Za-z]\{1,30\}\)\{0,1\}' emails`

Second, you are escaping spaces with backslashes inside single quotes. While most implementations of `grep` will handle this as simple spaces, the posix standard considers this undefined: *The interpretation of an ordinary character preceded by a backslash ( '\' ) is undefined.*

There may be additional problems, but we can't know without knowing the syntax of your file and what you want to `grep`

Comment: `[A-Z]` is also undefined other than in the `C`/`POSIX` locale per posix. In practice, it generally matches more characters (even possibly collating sequences made of more than one character) than the 26 letters of the english alphabet.

Comment: Given that the pattern is not anchored, the `\( [A-Za-z]\{1,30\}\)\{0,1\}` is also superfluous. Possibly `-x` is missing.