# One line read verification

Tags: variable, read, verification

I have this `read` operation:

```
read -p "Please enter your name:" username
```

How could I verify the users name, in one line?

If it's not possible in a sane way in one line, maybe a Bash function putted inside a variable is a decent solution?

---

Name is just an example, it could be a password or any other common form value.

Verifying means here: Requesting the user to insert the name twice and to ensure the two values are the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the email matching regex in basic regex for grep?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194912/what-is-the-email-matching-regex-in-basic-regex-for-grep)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That the user typed (or, possibly, copied and pasted...) the same thing twice is usually done with two `read` calls, two variables, and a comparison.

```
read -p "Please enter foo" bar1
read -p "Please enter foo again" bar2
if [ "$bar1" != "$bar2" ]; then
   echo >&2 "foos did not match"
   exit 1
fi
```

This could instead be done with a `while` loop and condition variable that repeats the prompts-and-checks until a match is made, or possibly abstracted into a function call if there are going to be a lot of prompts for input.

Comment: I assume that if I want to use this code in various other scripts, I could put the `if` statement and its variable in a file, source that file, and then use the two `read` operations on another file. Is that correct?

Comment: for multiple usages a function would be more appropriate

Answer (score 3):

To expand on thrig's answer and include the function you had requested:

**Function**

```
enter_thing () {
    unset matched
    while [[ -z "$matched" ]]; do
        read -rp "Please enter $@: " thing1
        read -rp "Please re-enter $@: " thing2
        if [[ "$thing1" == "$thing2" ]]; then
            matched=1
        else
            echo "Error! Input does not match" >&2
        fi
    done
    echo "$thing2"
}
```

In a script you could call it like:

```
username=$(enter_thing "name")
email=$(enter_thing "email")
password=$(enter_thing "password")
```

Comment: Thx, I thumbed up.