# How to grep emails out of a file?

Tags: grep

I have a long list of email addresses I need to extract, however I can't find the right way to do it.

The data is is structured similar to this.

```
Patabee meeta needo buffalos@outlook.com pizz bees
Needo target@outlook.com hama lines question
unix search exchange helpme@outlook.com extracts
```

One thing that is consistent in my data is the email domains.

Currently i have...

```
grep -oniT @outlook.com /path/to/file/of/emails/and/such.txt
```

which returns a nice output of..

```
3624   :@outlook.com
3625   :@outlook.com
3626   :@outlook.com
3630   :@outlook.com
3631   :@outlook.com
3632   :@outlook.com
3633   :@outlook.com
3634   :@outlook.com
3635   :@outlook.com
```

I need it however to select the whole email address, not just the domain (which is what im currently searching.

How can i make grep select the entire field that it found the matching string, but not the entire line?

Comment: Related: [What is the email matching regex in basic regex for grep?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194912/what-is-the-email-matching-regex-in-basic-regex-for-grep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-o` prints only the part matching the pattern, so you'll need to extend the pattern to include the part before the `@`. With the addresses in your sample, catching any non-blanks should do:

```
$ grep -oniTE '[^[:blank:]]+@outlook.com'  foo 
  1:    buffalos@outlook.com
  2:    target@outlook.com
  3:    helpme@outlook.com
```

In general, though, email addresses are ***difficult*** to parse (they can contain quoted whitespace), and the above will miss some valid email addresses (as well as include some invalid ones). See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax) and the relevant standards for the gory details.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution using **grep**:

```
grep -E -o "\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b" /path/to/file/of/emails/and/such.txt
```

This will get all email addresses in the file. You may want to adapt the regex to match only a specific domain.

> -E, --extended-regexp Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression
>
> -o, --only-matching Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.